# onStateChange doesn't get called when wrapped in React.Component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to wrap the NavigationContainer in React component for screen tracking, this approach worked well in V4 but fails in V5 unfortunately. The follow-up question is: will it be possible to wrap it in a function component and not in the react component to have the ability to use *hooks*? (must admit I am relatively new to react)
Will really appreciate any assistance

*App.js*

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function MyDrawer() {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerType="front" drawerPosition="left">
      <Drawer.Screen name="Properties" component={PropertiesTabs} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

const AppContainer = function App() {
  return <NavigationContainer>{MyDrawer()}</NavigationContainer>;
}
export default with(AppContainer);
```

*Wrapper.tsx*

```
export function with(Component: any) {
        class PNDContainer extends React.Component {
        debounce;
        componentDidMount() {
            console.log('PND Mounted - First Time Screen');
        }
       componentWillUnmount() { }
       render() {
            return (<Component onStateChange={() => {
                console.log('Screen Changed Doesnt get Called !!!');
            }} />);
        }
    }
    return PNDContainer;
}
```

**Expected Behavior**

- *onStateChange* should be called, in the V4 the same approach  did trigger the *onNavigationStateChange*

**Enviroment** 
@react-navigation/native 5.7.0 
react-native 0.61.5 
node 13.10.1 
yarn 1.22.1

I can understand why it doesnt work, as I am passing a function element that has no such prop *onStateChange*, in V4 *CreatAppContainer* returned a component that had the prop *onNavigationStateChange*
So I would like to call the function get the element and "inject" my *onStateChange* implementation, but I think react doesnt work that way (its more like imperative way and react is a declarative framework) so what will be a better approach?
So I tried to debug in chrome to see the *onStateChange*, no luck...
I think that I misunderstand the concepts, I read the following  [React Function Components](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component)

**Edit** 
For now the only solution that worked for me is to wrap my component in *NavigationContainer* 
 and returned it

```
<NavigationContainer onStateChange={() => {console.log('ProbablynewScreen');}}>{Component()}
  </NavigationContainer>);
```

In that case, I noticed that discovering drawer is not that simple there is no clue in the state for the drawer and if I use Class component (unfortunately currently I must) I have no hooks, so how would I discover a drawer open/close ?

Comment: Why the downvote? if my question isn't good/clear enough please correct me and I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*App.js*

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function MyDrawer(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer onStateChange={props.onStateChange}>
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerType="front" drawerPosition="left">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Properties" component={PropertiesTabs} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};
export default with(MyDrawer)
```

*With.tsx*

```
export function with(Component: any) {
    class PNDContainer extends React.Component {
        child: any;
        componentDidMount() {
            //debugger;
            console.log('PND Mounted - First Time Screen');
        }
        componentWillUnmount() { }
        render() {
            debugger;
            return (<Component onStateChange={(state) => {
                debugger;
                console.log('Screen Changed');
            }} />)
        }
    }
    return PNDContainer;
}
```

Thanks to WhiteBear

Comment: How can this be implemented as a functional component in Typescript? More specifically, how does the onStateChange be implemented?